# Is there away to mock UUID in Mockito without using powermock?

Tags: junit, mockito, powermock

I want to mock an object that has a uuid value  but I don't want to install powermock.

Comment: Please share the code with us that gives you problems. In general, mocking UUID seems like the wrong approach. That class is nothing but a data container. And you dont mock those, you simply create instances that contain the data you want to be used. Like: you dont mock a list; you simply create a normal list and put in the data that you want to be in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your easiest way to achieve this will be to wrap up your UUID generation.

Suppose you have a class using `UUID.randomUUID`

```
public Clazz MyClazz{

public void doSomething(){
    UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();
}

}
```

The UUID geneartion is completely tied to the JDK implementation. A solution would to be wrap the UUID generation that could be replaced at test time with a different dependency.

Spring has an interface for this exact senario, https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/IdGenerator.html

I'm not suggesting you use Spring for this interface just informational purposes.

You can then wrap up your UUID generation,

```
public class MyClazz{

private final idGeneartor;

public MyClazz(IdGeneartor idGenerator){
    this.idGenerator = idGenerator;
}

public void doSomething(){
    UUID uuid =idGenerator.generateId();
}
```

You can then have multiple implementations of UUID geneartion depending on your needs

```
public JDKIdGeneartor implements IdGenerator(){

    public UUID generateId(){
       return UUID.randomUUID();
    }
}
```

And a hardcoded impl that will always return the same UUID.

```
public HardCodedIdGenerator implements IdGenerator(){

    public UUID generateId(){
       return UUID.nameUUIDFromBytes("hardcoded".getBytes());
    }
}
```

At test time you can construct your object with the HardCodedIdGeneartor allowing you to know what the generated ID will be and assert more freely.

Comment: I suppose this would work if I am creating the generator in a class and then can mock that class (something `val mockUtilities = mock(classOf[utilities]) when (mockUtilities.generateId).thenReturn(1)`. How should I do this if my methods are in an `object`. Could you please look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55016630/can-i-and-how-mock-methods-of-an-global-onbject

Answer (score 1):

I used to use `MockedStatic` with JUnit 5 like this:

```java
    import org.junit.jupiter.api.AfterEach;
    import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
    import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
    import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
    import org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoExtension;
    import org.mockito.MockedStatic;
    import java.util.UUID;
    
    @ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
    public class MyTest {
        private static MockedStatic<UUID> mockUuid;
        private static final UUID constUuid = UUID.randomUUID();
        
        @InjectMocks
        private MyClass myClass;
        
        @BeforeEach
        public void setUp() {
            mockUuid = mockStatic(UUID.class);
            mockUuid.when(UUID::randomUUID).thenReturn(constUuid);
        }
        

        @AfterEach
        public void closeResources() {
            mockUuid.close();
        }

        @Test
        public void testMyMethod() {
            ...
        }
    }
```

with this you can be sure your "random" UUID will always be equal to `constUuid`, meaning whenever your methods call `UUID.randomUUID()`, it will always return the same value. So, in your test you can assume that

```java
    @Test
    public void testMyMethod() {
        assertEquals(constUuid, myClass.myMethod());
    }
```

of course, if the method, e.g. just returns the generated value

```java
    import java.util.UUID;
    
    public class MyClass {
        public UUID myMethod() {
            return UUID.randomUUID();
        }
        
        ...
    }
```